# How do you "make" a soliton? (recent peer-reviewed theoretical work in FTL travel)

Tags: propulsion, physics, design-alternative, interstellar-travel, speed-of-light

I've just read an Article on the new approach on Warp Drives Dr. Erik Lentz describes. Instead of creating a bubble with negative energy density, he describes a Soliton in spacetime, which he apparently calculated based on General Relativity. Using huge amounts of energy, the gravitational forces should bend space in such a way that it compresses in front and dilates behind a spacecraft. I was wondering how that would work "in practice".

Obviously it wouldn't. But, for example, it is entirely possible to create wormholes, and the step by step instructions are basically:

1. Get yourself a black hole. If you can't make one, storebought is fine.
2. Use an equal but not as dense amount of exotic matter, and pour it into the black hole.
3. This will neutralize the gravitational forces, but will still "force" the hole in spacetime the black hole originally created open.
4. Now depending on which branch of physics you ask, this hole will either lead into the past, another universe, or to the same point in spacetime. You can freely move these wormholes by applying charges to them.

Again, purely theoretical, but if we had the means, even a little kid could build a wormhole, so to speak. So, while I get the theory behind this new approach, I don't quite get how exactly this would be applied in the real world. As far as I know, extremely dense bodies don't move above c, so how would the warp drive accomplish this?

---

- [Press Release](https://www.uni-goettingen.de/en/3240.html?id=6192)
- The peer-reviewed paper (paywalled): Erik W Lentz 2021 Class. Quantum Grav. 38 075015 [Breaking the warp barrier: hyper-fast solitons in Einstein–Maxwell-plasma theory](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6382/abe692)

Discussions in the popular press:

- Physics World: [Spacecraft in a ‘warp bubble’ could travel faster than light, claims physicist](https://physicsworld.com/a/spacecraft-in-a-warp-bubble-could-travel-faster-than-light-claims-physicist/),
- Centauri Dreams: [FTL: Thoughts on a New Paper by Erik Lentz](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2021/03/11/ftl-thoughts-on-a-new-paper-by-erik-lentz/)
- Sci News: [Faster-Than-Light Travel is Possible, Theoretical Study Suggests](http://www.sci-news.com/physics/superluminal-travel-09448.html)
- Futurism: [Peer-Reviewed Paper Claims Faster-Than-Light Travel is Possible; The New Model Relies on Conventional Physics to Achieve Warp Speed, and That's a Big Deal](https://futurism.com/the-byte/paper-claims-faster-than-light-travel-is-possible)

Comment: From the abstract of the Lenz-paper "The solitons are also shown to be capable of being sourced from the stress–energy of a conducting plasma and classical electromagnetic fields. " That may be your 'in practice' construction of GR solitons. I don't understand that part of the paper though, which shows how reasonable the EM-fields needed would be.

Comment: I love the optimism in our theories, and for sure they're the best we have... But in science, theory isn't enough to say wormholes exist/can be made. You have to demonstrate experimentally, because all theories have limitations, and you don't know if you've overstepped them. So first things first: we need to demonstrate in a lab environment that wormholes exist and can be made. *Then* we can start saying that making wormholes is basically this or that recipe. I don't think we can say we know what the recipe would be or if there would be one. Has this ever been done and validated in a lab?

Comment: Plus, there are serious limitations to relativity and quantum mechanics in the areas where they overlap. They are phenomenally accurate in their predictions where they don't overlap, but they completely fall apart where they do. They pretty much start spewing nonsense that you can't and shouldn't trust. And I'm pretty sure wormholes fall right in that overlap zone. I would be supremely skeptical of any predictions made there until we at last close the divide, and that will take at least a sound theory of quantum gravity. We're not there yet, and I don't think we can say wormholes are possible.

Comment: Nevertheless, very interesting question, and one that should be entertained, so long as we remember that they are right at the extreme edge of what we think we know. My guess is that neither relativity nor quantum mechanics by themselves are enough for us to answer them, and it may be that whatever new theories ultimately supercede them will tell us unexpected things about things like wormholes.

Comment: @user39728: Your comments are completely missing the point. Lentz's paper has nothing to do with wormholes.

Comment: A preprint of that paper is available [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07125).  Since any of these mechanisms result in causality violation (ie time machines) if they're going to be useful (specifically: if you can get back to where you came from), I'd strongly assume that they get ruled out.

Comment: I was responding to the OP's comment that even a kid could make a wormhole if we had the technology. It's not just a tech barrier. We literally can't tell if wormholes are real physical things or if they're predictions gone wrong. No amount of tech will help you make wormholes if wormholes aren't real. That's all.

Comment: Also, it's not the first time theoretical studies have suggested we can travel faster than light or even back in time. Every so often you get a new one suggesting something mind-boggling. And it's great to exercise your mathematical imagination. But it's all to be taken with a great grain of salt. Because not once have those theoretical studies passed muster in the lab. And I understand these things aren't easy to design experiments for. But the conclusions are so earth-shattering and the theories in such questionable state that you just have to demonstrate experimentally, I think.

Comment: Being able to create a bubble that can move at superluminal speeds, does not mean that we can actually "accelerate" it to such speeds. The paper solves the problem of negative mass, but still does not solve the problem of acquiring superluminal matter. ([TLDR](https://youtu.be/PA66ah9b0U4?t=691))

Comment: @Vepir Yes, that makes sense. Thank you.